# High memory usage in java program (lots of recursion with arrays)

Tags: java

I am having a problem that has been bugging me for few days now. I am doing a college asignment where i have to multiply 2 big numbers (each number can be up to 10000 digits), for that reason i have to use arrays. 
I have to use naive divide and conquer method using a special formula and it is working, i get the **correct output**. 
The **problem** though is that program's ram usage peaks at 715MB while the college server which will test my outputs only permits peaks less then 10MB !
I used visualVM to get some statistics and it shows that at the end of main method i have over 25.000 int arrays opened, which obviously means that garbage collector won't clean them. I tried manualy removing arrays by array = null but it has no effect. Even more, size of arrays in program has no effect on ram usage, if i make all arrays of size 10000 or if i make them smaller, ram usage is still 715MB. Nothing i tried has made even 1Kb difference in ram usage. What am i doing wrong ?

import java.util.*;

public class Naloga2 {

```
static int firstNumberLength;
static int secondNumberLength;
static int count;   

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    firstNumberLength = 0;
    secondNumberLength = 0;

    start(args);    

    System.out.println("Check memory usage and press any key");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.nextLine();

}

static void printArray(int[] a, int length) {

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) System.out.print(a[i]);
    System.out.println();

}

static void printArrayNoNewLine(int[] a, int length) {

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) System.out.print(a[i]);       

}

static int[] obrniTabelo(int[] tabela, int dolzinaTabele) {

    int[] novaTabela = new int[firstNumberLength + secondNumberLength];

    for(int i=0;i<dolzinaTabele;i++) {                      
        novaTabela[i] = tabela[dolzinaTabele - i - 1];              
    }

    return novaTabela;

}

static void readNumbers(int[] a, int[] b) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    String temp1 = "1814760427359093701773634896055154238604621068079345503988844965147764988324706056377247443923778795928948605699104801900306908537904148935233121873094936503998915865745862371767010306054062906768898568957847355344002122176514654744790212626620584107994283130875249861052935175219132106429755509971192581933953801388381188460986660581979158129483917001271702223407654800335931472019985629221607213865018069283189966200621625300134";
    String temp2 = "97512060979417027247066473890437645860252983792423404628415959133594150264916901106891610016700858329869623573382829998749019896997745761637960733420798357562414782788848733769941600640359229331196534760613331886605807310229536529299047661042932723686940506490467693828359124032044766542882911974806517818312853119004786073768385133003204124346870416398337405003873260912959735781385513491033737150032844086069531948792576932151901897811096445945530418292434773408981209319417729967465446257427784080363848953538788259430643983374127862528899812266699138053211381274176090725067261872355977420957399650610409274997690573284775365452519492094199150332836530293736450846555043855394905294740708235099468050036111579819724363868989787277506605869758256547608040247461962450653542826639244219294087064008107664753142535552152880164752050308970662812876788273331513642358933315796998961151437131149920030780118660547331872894504653590764949555989125948482198399816531852334011945495558518939896596518131272300822293060394523495515862731265541258202053045616084735425799134171661329905235453695720851880506732702524221829703587444566936446048580047972702945614278702240636251666791566010549308512827456794434888225729025123511920552233844557238739513734443927750297099927757353661453279831551902974620243283691649185034824294607701567938075725970651517685420371143465190361476038554928265834067374093805712372282561321345651430079136538347289657425955000036298701183558407903511884604388721633166414508318158";

    firstNumberLength = temp1.length();
    secondNumberLength = temp2.length();

    for(int i=0;i<firstNumberLength;i++) a[i] = temp1.charAt(i) - 48;
    for(int i=0;i<secondNumberLength;i++) b[i] = temp2.charAt(i) - 48;

}

static void start(String[] args) {

    int a[] = new int[10000];
    int b[] = new int[10000];           

    readNumbers(a, b);  

    int aa[] = new int[firstNumberLength];
    int bb[] = new int[secondNumberLength];

    for(int i=0;i<firstNumberLength;i++) aa[i] = a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<secondNumberLength;i++) bb[i] = b[i];

    dv(aa, bb, "count");    
}   

static int[] steviloPlusSteviloRu (int[] a, int[] b, int[] tempDolzina) { 

    a = obrniTabelo(a, tempDolzina[0]);
    b = obrniTabelo(b, tempDolzina[1]);
    int prenos = 0;

    if(tempDolzina[0] < tempDolzina[1]) { 

        tempDolzina[0] = tempDolzina[1]; 

    }

    int limit = tempDolzina[1];

    for(int i=0;i<tempDolzina[1];i++) {

        a[i] = a[i] + b[i] + prenos;

        prenos = 0;

        if(a[i] > 9) {

            prenos = a[i] / 10;
            a[i] = a[i] % 10;               

        }

    }

    while(prenos > 0) {

        if(prenos > 9) System.out.println("prenos nad 9, error !");         

        a[limit] = a[limit] + prenos;
        prenos = 0;
        if(a[limit] > 9) { 

            prenos = a[limit] / 10;
            a[limit] = a[limit] % 10;

        }

        if(limit == tempDolzina[0]) tempDolzina[0]++;
        limit++;

    }       

    a = obrniTabelo(a, tempDolzina[0]);

    return a;

}

static int[] stevkaKratSteviloDv(int[] a, int b, int[] length) { // dv - mnozenje z stevko

    int prenos = 0;
    a = obrniTabelo(a, length[0]);

    for(int i=0;i<length[0];i++) {

        a[i] = a[i] * b + prenos;
        prenos = 0;
        if(a[i] > 9) {

            prenos = a[i] / 10;
            a[i] = a[i] % 10;

        }           
    }       

    if(prenos > 0 ) {

        if(prenos > 9) System.out.println("prenos vecji od 9 !!");
        a[length[0]] = prenos;
        length[0]++;

    }

    a = obrniTabelo(a, length[0]);

    return a;
}

static void dv(int[] a, int[] b, String m) { // dk

    int mode = 0;
    if(m.equals("count")) mode = 1;

    if(mode == 1) {

        printArray(a, firstNumberLength);   
        printArray(b, secondNumberLength);

    }       

    int[] dolzine = {firstNumberLength, secondNumberLength};                    
    int[] dolzina = {firstNumberLength, secondNumberLength};
    int[] len1 = {firstNumberLength};
    int[] len2 = {secondNumberLength};
    int[] len3 = new int[1];
    int[] rezultat = dvRek(a, b, len1, len2, len3, mode);

    rezultat = odstrani(rezultat, len3);

    if(mode == 0) {             
        printArray(rezultat, len3[0]);
    } else System.out.println(count);






}

static int[] subSet(int[] aa, int[] length, int mode) { // returns subset, depends on mode

    int dolzina = length[0];

    if(dolzina < 2) {           
        System.out.println("error, dolzina je " + dolzina);
        return aa;
    }

    int start = 0;
    int stop = dolzina / 2;
    if(mode == 1) { 

        start = dolzina / 2; 
        stop = dolzina;

    }

    int[] temp = new int[length[0]];        
    int index = 0;

    for(int i=start;i<stop;i++) {

        temp[index] = aa[i];
        index++;

    }

    length[0] = (stop - start);

    aa = null;      
    return temp;

}

static int[] dodajNicle(int[] aa, int[] length, int num) { // adds zeroes, basicly multiplying with 10^num

    int[] temp = new int[length[0] + num];  
    for(int i=0;i<length[0];i++) temp[i] = aa[i];   



    for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {            
        temp[length[0]] = 0;
        length[0]++;                
    }       

    aa = null;
    return temp;    

}

static int[] dopolni(int[] aa, int[] length, int num) { // adds num zeros at start and returns

    aa = obrniTabelo(aa, length[0]);

    int start = length[0];
    int end = start + num;


    for(int i=start;i<end;i++) aa[i] = 0;
    length[0] = length[0] + num;

    aa = obrniTabelo(aa, length[0]);

    return aa;

}

static int[] odstrani(int[] aa, int[] length) { // removes zeros from beginning

    aa = obrniTabelo(aa, length[0]);

    for(int i=(length[0]-1);i>0;i--)    
        if(aa[i] == 0) length[0]--;
        else break; 

    aa = obrniTabelo(aa, length[0]);


    return aa;

}

static int[] dvRek (int[] a, int[] b, int[] lengthA, int[] lengthB, int[] lengthC, int mode) {

    a = odstrani(a, lengthA);
    b = odstrani(b, lengthB);

    if(mode == 0)   {                   
        printArrayNoNewLine(a, lengthA[0]);
        System.out.print(" ");
        printArray(b, lengthB[0]);
    }

    if(lengthA[0] == 1) {

        if(a[0] == 0) {

            lengthC[0] = 1;             
            return new int[1];
        }           

        int temp = lengthB[0];

        int minus = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<temp;i++) {               
            if(b[i] == 0) minus++;
            if(b[i] > 0) break;             
        }

        count = count + temp - minus;

        b = stevkaKratSteviloDv(b, a[0], lengthB);          
        lengthC[0] = lengthB[0];
        lengthB[0] = temp;
        return b;

    } else if (lengthB[0] == 1) {


        if(b[0] == 0) {

            lengthC[0] = 1;             
            return new int[1];

        }           

        int temp = lengthA[0];



        int minus = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<temp;i++) {               
            if(a[i] == 0) minus++;
            if(a[i] > 0) break;             
        }

        count = count + temp - minus;       

        a = stevkaKratSteviloDv(a, b[0], lengthA);          
        lengthC[0] = lengthA[0];

        return a;

    } else {    

        if(lengthA[0] > lengthB[0]) {

            b = dopolni(b, lengthB, (lengthA[0] - lengthB[0])); 

        }                               
        else if (lengthA[0] < lengthB[0]) { 

            a = dopolni(a, lengthA, (lengthB[0] - lengthA[0]));

        }

        int[] a1Len = { lengthA[0] };
        int[] a0Len = { lengthA[0] }; 
        int[] b1Len = { lengthB[0] };
        int[] b0Len = { lengthB[0] };

        int[] a1 = subSet(a, a1Len, 0);
        int[] a0 = subSet(a, a0Len, 1);
        int[] b1 = subSet(b, b1Len, 0);
        int[] b0 = subSet(b, b0Len, 1);


        a = null;
        b = null;

        int[] temp = new int[1];
        int[] tempp = new int[1];


        temp[0] = b0Len[0]; 
        tempp[0] = a0Len[0];
        int[] a0b0 = dvRek(a0, b0, tempp, temp, lengthC, mode);
        int[] a0b0Len = { lengthC[0] };



        temp[0] = b1Len[0];     
        tempp[0] = a0Len[0];
        int[] a0b1 = dvRek(a0, b1, tempp, temp, lengthC, mode);
        int[] a0b1Len = { lengthC[0] };




        //a1b0          
        temp[0] = b0Len[0];     
        tempp[0] = a1Len[0];
        int[] a1b0 = dvRek(a1, b0, tempp, temp, lengthC, mode);
        int[] a1b0Len = { lengthC[0] };




        //a1b1  
        temp[0] = b1Len[0];     
        tempp[0] = a1Len[0];
        int[] a1b1 = dvRek(a1, b1, tempp, temp, lengthC, mode);
        int[] a1b1Len = { lengthC[0] };



        int n = lengthA[0];
        if(lengthB[0] > n) n = lengthB[0];

        if(n % 2 != 0) n++;

        int[] temp1 = dodajNicle(a1b1, a1b1Len, n );



        int[] dolzine = {a0b1Len[0], a1b0Len[0]};       
        int[] temp2 = steviloPlusSteviloRu(a0b1, a1b0, dolzine);



        temp2 = dodajNicle(temp2, dolzine, (n/2) );




        int[] dolzine1 = {a1b1Len[0], dolzine[0]};          
        int[] temp3 = steviloPlusSteviloRu(temp1, temp2, dolzine1);



        int[] dolzine2 = {dolzine1[0], a0b0Len[0] };
        int[] temp4 = steviloPlusSteviloRu(temp3, a0b0, dolzine2);


        lengthC[0] = dolzine2[0];               

        a = null;
        b = null;
        a0b0 = null;
        a1b0 = null;
        a0b1 = null;
        a1b1 = null;
        a0 = null;
        a1 = null;
        b0 = null;
        b1 = null;
        lengthA = null;
        lengthB = null;
        lengthC = null;
        temp = null;
        tempp = null;
        dolzine = null;
        dolzine1 = null;
        dolzine2 = null;
        temp1 = null;
        temp2 = null;
        temp3 = null;



        return temp4;

    }   

}
```

}

Comment: There's a difference between RAM usage and the memory your code needs. The JVM launches with default settings that may allocate a lot more memory than is necessary for your program to run. However having 25k int arrays means that there is probably a problem with your code.

Comment: Also using `xxx = null` makes no difference so you can remove those lines.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<firstNumberLength;i++) aa[i] = a[i];` can be written as `aa = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);` (and you don't need to initialize it first).

Comment: Please can you remove all the commented code and extraneous vertical whitespace?

Comment: Also: `Character.getNumericValue(temp1.charAt(i))` is a more descriptive (and robust) way of converting to the digit value than subtracting 48. (Even subtracting `'0'` would be more readable)

Comment: You should use OOP concept to store your results. Give variable a proper name so it is easy to read and understand. Meaningful method name also helpful. Your program logic is so long and complex which is hard for anyone having to help :)

Comment: Any idea why is ram usage of this program so high ? It would appear that arrays aren't deleted when they should be, why is that ?